# Nested Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, nested, conditional-operator

Having some issue with nested ternary :

**I have code :**

```
var genericName = Beauty;

setTitle = (!empty(shopOnline) ? shopOnline + ' | ' : '') 
    + (!empty(productName) ? productName + ' | ' : '') 
    + genericName;
```

I want scenario like:

1. if genericName is not empty - Shop Online | Product Name | Generic Name
2. if genericName is empty - Shop Online | Product Name

Currently I am getting the output of my code (if genericName is empty) - Shop Online | Product Name |

How we can add the nested ternary operator to remove " | " if genericName is empty after Product Name
( (!empty(productName) ? productName + ' | ' : '') )

Comment: While the filter/join method is significantly cleaner (assuming they're actually empty and don't contain whitespace), your original approach adds the `|` at the wrong time: it should be added if the "*next*" value isn't empty, not the *current* value. In general, any time you're "join"ing things, `join` is the way to go since it handles this logic for you--the only issue is making sure you're joining the right things, e.g., via some sort of `filter` etc.

Comment: You've asked an XY question (about your proposed solution instead of the problem). It would be better to ask about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
[shopOnline, productName, genericName].filter(Boolean).join(' | ')
```

Here [Boolean function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is given as a callback to filter out the falsy values like
`0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, ''`

You can also use your `empty()` as filter's callback

```
[shopOnline, productName, genericName].filter(i => !empty(i)).join(' | ')
```

Comment: A brief explanation would make this answer better. While the documentation addresses the individual methods, your overall approach would be helpful.